# Keep getting this error when trying to make a mysql database from this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I try to create this database and source it from the table:

```
CREATE DATABASE milestone3;
USE milestone3
source team21db.sql
```

> I get the error:
>
> ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'Phone' at row 1

I made the table below through vim and named it team21db.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OIT Storage` (
`Id` int(1) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`Name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Hard Drive` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`Phone`  varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Picked up?` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `OIT Storage` (`ID`, `Name`, `Hard Drive`, `Phone`, `Picked up?`) VALUES
    (1, 'John',' IDE',  '7203456789',' NO'),
    (2, 'Mason', 'SAS', '3035551234', 'YES'),
    (3, 'Jake', 'SCSI', '7196570123','NO'),
    (4, 'Matt', 'SCSI', '5671239090', 'NO'),
    (5, 'Helen', 'SATA','7195471423', 'YES')
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Might you have a trigger on the column?

Comment: Are you sure the table doesn't already exist with a different definition for that field?

Comment: Which field? @Uueerdo

Comment: Can't explain the error on `Phone`, but you certainly can't store the three character word `YES` in a `varchar(2) NOT NULL`.  Also, there's a lot you will hate yourself for, later, if you don't stick with the set of lower case letters, numbers, and underscore (first character alpha) for your column names, and true/false values should be handled as boolean values, not strings.

Comment: My guess is the value is being interpreted as an integer, and the values exceed the maximum size of a 32 bit signed int.  but how that's happening is a mystery. I can't reproduce this error.

Comment: @RyanWilliams the `Phone` field; as Bohemian above me suggested if the value passed is being interpreted as an integer (perhaps due to `Phone` being an `INT` rather the `varchar(10)` you are expecting), that could cause such an issue. _Never forget `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does not update the table's field definitions._